# C++ typedef with strange scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, scope, standards, typedef

I have to port some C++ code and found this strange typedef:

```
typedef uint32_t SomeClassName::* ptr;
```

The target compiler is MSVC++. As far as I understand, this just creates an alias for the `uint32_t*` named `ptr`. The part with `SomeClassName::` does nothing useful and should be treated as an error by the compliant C++ compiler. Am I right or wrong?

Also, found [Unusual scope resolution operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975678/unusual-scope-resolution-operator) question on SO, that possibly answers this question, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Is this possible a pointer to member? I'm not exactly familiar with the syntax, it's confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pointer to member. Specifically a variable of type `ptr` can point to any `uint32_t` data member of `SomeClassName`. It can be used like this:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    float c;
};

Foo foo;
int Foo::* ptr;

ptr = &Foo::a;
foo.*ptr = 10; //Set foo.a to 10

ptr = &Foo::b;
foo.*ptr = 15; //Set foo.b to 15

//ptr = &Foo::c; //Won't compile
```